# Create NSDate from 24h NSString return null

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have `NSString` in 24h format like that:

```
NSString *a = @"10:00";
NSString *b = @"23:59";
```

How can I get `NSDate` with `NSString` b?

I using: 
 + `setDateFormat: @"HH:mm"` ==> It's work both for a and b when phone setting is 24h. 
 + `setDateFormat: @"hh:mm"` ==> It's only work for a when phone setting is am/pm.

My full code, with self.timeInit is NSString with 24h format:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:self.timeInit];

    if (!date){
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
        date = [dateFormat dateFromString:self.timeInit];
        NSLog(@"Date 2: %@", date);
    }

    if (!date){
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"H:mm"];

        date = [dateFormat dateFromString:self.timeInit];
        NSLog(@"Date 3: %@", date);
    }

    NSLog(@"Date: %@", date);
    if (date){
        [self.timePickerUI setDate:date];
    }
```

Comment: I take a lot of time to test & research it. But I can not found a solution.

I try to convert "23:59" to "11:59 PM" but NSDate still null.

Comment: I can't get you, you said: "setDateFormat: @"HH:mm" ==> It's work both for a and b when phone setting is 24h." => you did  get date from string b?  So what is your problem ?

Comment: Problem when user go to Settings, and change 24h format to AM/PM then NSDate return null.

Comment: How are you getting strings `a` and `b`?

Comment: It is just string, see my edit (full code)

Comment: try `[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];`

Comment: @"hh:mm a" still return null

Comment: try this

 `NSString *str = @"13:49";
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:str];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
str = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];`

Comment: It return date = null & str = null

Comment: check your `self.timeInit` is right format ? I check your code with `NSString *a = @"10:00";
NSString *b = @"23:59";` `with dateFormat = @"HH:mm"` it work perfectly both 24h and 12h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You force your own locale on the NSDateFormatter, so it ignores the settings of the user.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
[dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:self.timeInit];
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is work. I try setLocale before, but DateFormat is wrong. So, when setLocale, NSDateFormatter will overwrite settings of user.
Thanks :)