# TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined and offset exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

I'm trying to achieve smooth scrolling with jQuery and smoothscroll.js. I have done a lot of research as to why I'm getting this error in dev tools but I can't seem to figure it out:

> TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined

This is my code:

```
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
// MENU SMOOTH SCROLLING
/*----------------------------------------------------*/  
$(".main-menu a, .logo a, .home-logo-text a, .home-logo a, .scroll-to").bind('click', function(event) {
    $(".main-menu a").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');         
    var headerH = $('.navigation').outerHeight();

    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top - headerH + 'px'
    }, {
        duration: 1200,
        easing: "easeInOutExpo"
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

This is the html:

```
<body class="onepage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navigation">
<div id="load"></div>




<!-- START PAGE WRAP -->    
<div class="page-wrap">


<!-- START HOME SECTION -->    
<div id="home" class="home-parallax">
  <div class="home-text-wrapper">

      <div class="home-logo-text">
        <a href="index.html#about">Welcome to Jarvis</a>
      </div>

       <div id="home-slider" class="flexslider">            
            <ul class="slides styled-list">

            <li class="home-slide"><p class="home-slide-content">We are <span class="highlight">Creative</span> Nerds</p></li>

            <li class="home-slide"><p class="home-slide-content">We are <span class="highlight">crazy</span> Coders</p></li>

            <li class="home-slide"><p class="home-slide-content">We <span class="highlight">love</span> Pizzas</p></li>

            </ul>
       </div><!-- END FLEXSLIDER -->
    </div><!-- END HOME TEXT WRAPPER -->
 </div><!-- END HOME SECTION -->



<!-- START NAVIGATION -->
<nav class="light sticky-nav navigation">
 <!-- START CONTAINER -->   
  <div class="container clearfix">          
      <div class="four columns">            
          <!-- START LOGO -->   
          <div class="logo large">
           <a href="index.html#home"><img src="images/logo.png" title="logo" alt="Logo"/></a>
          </div>
          <!-- END LOGO -->         
      </div><!-- END FOUR COLUMNS -->   


      <div class="twelve columns">                  
          <!-- START NAVIGATION MENU ITEMS -->
          <ul class="main-menu large nav" id="nav">
              <li><a href="index.html#home">Home</a></li>                
              <li><a href="index.html#about">About</a></li>
          </ul>
          <!-- END NAVIGATION MENU ITEMS -->                
      </div><!-- END TWELVE COLUMNS --> 
  </div><!-- END CONTAINER -->  
</nav>
<!-- END NAVIGATION -->


<!-- START ABOUT US SECTION --> 
<div id="about" class="page">

    <div class="container"> 
       <div class="row">    
        <div class="sixteen columns">            
            <!-- START TITLE -->                
            <div class="title">
              <h1>About Jarvis</h1>
              <div class="subtitle">
                  <p>we are utmost <span class="highlight">Creative Agency</span> located in Melbourne, Australia. Praesent rhoncus nunc <span class="highlight">vitae metus</span> condimentum viverra.</p>
              </div><!-- END SUBTITLE -->
            </div><!-- END TITLE -->                               
        </div><!-- END SIXTEEN COLUMNS -->  
       </div><!-- END ROW -->         
      </div><!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

Comment: You're calling `top` on `offset()` which is returning undefined. This leads me to believe your `$(this).attr("href")` value is not a valid selector, or is not being found in the DOM. We need to see your HTML to diagnose the problem exactly.

Comment: What return from `$(this).attr("href")`?

Comment: Rory, I've added the html.

Answer (score 1):

Please check element is exist or not before got top property of offset() function:

```js
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
// MENU SMOOTH SCROLLING
/*----------------------------------------------------*/  
$(".main-menu a, .logo a, .home-logo-text a, .home-logo a, .scroll-to").bind('click', function(event) {
    $(".main-menu a").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');         
    var headerH = $('.navigation').outerHeight();
    var destinateEle = $($(this).attr("href"));

    if (destinateEle.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: destinateEle.offset().top - headerH
    }, {
        duration: 1200,
        easing: "easeInOutExpo"
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

After read you update HTML, I have to change js to remove "index.html".
Jquery('index.html#your-id') will always return empty element.

```js
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
// MENU SMOOTH SCROLLING
/*----------------------------------------------------*/  
$(".main-menu a, .logo a, .home-logo-text a, .home-logo a, .scroll-to").bind('click', function(event) {
    $(".main-menu a").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');         
    var headerH = $('.navigation').outerHeight();
    var queryIDArr = $(this).attr("href").split('#');
    if (queryIDArr.length < 2) return;
    var queryID = queryIDArr[1];
    var destinateEle = $('#' + queryID);

    if (destinateEle.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: destinateEle.offset().top - headerH
    }, {
        duration: 1200,
        easing: "easeInOutExpo"
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: This stops the error from occuring, but the scrolling function does not work.

Comment: Answers that simply post code aren't particularly useful, especially for future readers of your answer that have a similar problem, but not the exact same problem. Please explain what the problem with the code in the question is and what changes or additions you've made in the code in your answer to solve those problems.

Comment: @EmmanuelYakubu: Because you config wrong href value to scrollTo. Please check again.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Every 1 line code better 1000 words.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Please don't vote down my answer if you don't have any better answer. Thanks.

Comment: @SLyHuy I have added my html. can you find anything wrong with my href values?

Comment: You should only using href="#anchor-to-your-element-with-id". No need add "index.html#bla-bla-bla"

Comment: @SLyHuy "Every 1 of line code is better than 1000 words" absolutely not. If someone else does it all for you then you don't really learn how to fix it. You don't understand why it happens and next time OP needs help with his code he still won't understand what's happening, and will use stack overflow as a coding service / copy paste source. You don't learn to code by looking at code - you learn to code by getting problems, fixing them and learning how you fixed it.

Comment: @h2ooooooo you should read the code to find how it is. If don't you can ask me, lol.

Comment: @SLyHuy Please look at the correspondance you've had with OP. You gave all the answers away without explaining why and OP blindly just copy pasted code. Next time OP has a string that is "ble-ble-ble" instead, for all you know he won't know how to fix it, because last time all he did was copy paste code from stackoverflow. Look at [this answer for one of your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29161868/247893). It very clearly explains *what* you need to do to fix the issue and doesn't just provide you with code. You don't explain someone how to do math by calculating the answer for them.

Comment: @h2ooooooo Oke, I got your mean. Oke, next time I will add more explaining. Thank you.